# Smoothing multiple combined vector translations

Tags: c++, vector, glm

I am currently working on my arm/weapon rig for an fps game written in a custom engine. I am to the point where I am implementing the movement of the arms/weapon (hereby referred to as weapon), for example to illustrate movement while walking, movement when swinging arms with mouse, and movement when jumping. I am doing this by calculating vectors for each of these independently and then adding them together to produce a `finalVec` which is the location of the weapon rig in the scene.

So for example, if I want to move the weapon back by `0.03` units and down by `0.013` units at a speed of `0.1` units per second I create a Tweener as such:

`this->weaponPullBackTweener = std::make_unique<vel::Tweener>(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.013f, 0.03f), 0.1f);`

I then call a method on this class every tick passing in the frame delta time and it produces a vector between the first and second initialization parameter. I use this same methodology for producing the other aforementioned vectors (minus the arm sway which is more complicated since it uses mouse input), and add them together, then set weapon translation to their summation as below:

```
glm::vec3 finalVec = sightPos;
finalVec += pullBackPos;
finalVec.x += swayXYPos.x + walkPos.x;
finalVec.y += swayXYPos.y + walkPos.y + jumpPos.y;

armRig->getTransform().setTranslation(finalVec);
```

This produces the following result which [can be viewed in this video](https://youtu.be/R9J0q3lTrDA). It works, but since each vector completes it's cycle at a different rate, the result can be a bit jarring (most apparent when switching weapon from hip to iron sight aiming).

I've been attempting to come up with a solution to this for awhile now, and I seem to keep hitting a wall (as I am quite novice at game development). Therefore I am reaching out to see if anyone here would be able to suggest a methodology for correcting this, or implementing it in a different way as to smooth out the movement.

One thing that came to mind was maybe instead of using the vectors directly, finding the direction for each and then adding the directions together and using a constant velocity, but then since each needs to run at a different speed, they would end up not ending where they should end, unless I'm over/under thinking that potential solution?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your demo and it looks very cool! I had a little trouble interpreting the question so I am going to restate it and you let me know if I misunderstood you:
Your goal is to tween (change over time) several vectors from a start value to an end value. And the issue is that the duration of these changes is not equal.

In other words, you want vector A to become vector A' over t seconds.
And at the same time, you want vector B to become vector B' over t seconds (same t).

I think the issue here is that the magnitude of the translation varies between the cases. Instead of tweening based on deltaTime I would suggest lerping the position instead.

```
nextVal = lerp( curVal, goalVal, deltaTime * speedFactor );
```

Ideally, this approach can be applied separately to each vector and if the third argument is equal to 0.1 then all the vectors will progress 1/10 of the way to their goal. This may work well for a continuous operation where goal is constantly changing. But depending on your use case, you may have better results if you set a variable called lerpProgress and you reset it to 0 every time you have a new goal position and then increment lerpProgress overtime.

```
lerpProgress = Math.Clamp01( lerpProgress + deltaTime );     
nextVal = lerp( curVal, goalVal, lerpProgress  );
```

And just to be clear here, you would be computing a nextVal for any of the vectors you are moving but lerpProgress would be shared.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. What I'm actually after is: vector A to become vector A' over t seconds and vector B to become vector B' over t' seconds (different amount of seconds), but eliminate the sharp visible switch of direction when combining the two (after one reaches it's end point before the other), which at this point (unless I'm mistaken) does not appear to be mathematically possible (can not advance at different rates and complete at the same time (without adjusting distance)).

Comment: If you have two vectors being applied and then you stop applying one mid-way, you will observe a change in direction.